# select multiple columns with group by of one column django orm

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-views

I trying to get the name, today_date, date_2 from event table with group by name of the event with sql I am able to get the details but while using django orm I am getting duplicate records.

select name, today_date, date_2 from event group by name; --> SQL Query

Can anyone help me to convert above SQL query to django ORM query?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score -1):

```
Event.objects.all().values('name', 'today_date', 'date_2').group_by('name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay I am receiving 'queryset' object has no attribute 'group_by' error.

Comment: I am using django 2.2